# What to use to see the properties (size, framerate, number of samples, channels etc) of a .caf file?

Tags: macos

I'm looking for a Mac OS X console or GUI program that can display the properties (size, framerate, number of samples, channels) of a .caf file.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  I'd assume OS X as it's .caf you're working with, but please clarify.

Comment: Indeed I use OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of opensource programs which can handle the Core Audio format.  The most notable of which is [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).  This includes the [ffprobe](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) command which can report on many different aspects of an audio file.